# If two column values match, add one character value, if they do not match, add a different character value in a new column in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I obtained this sample from another post.

```
Sample#  Au  Au_ppb  
3000    0.2  0.2    
3001    0.2  >3      
3002    0.2  0.2    
3003    0.2  0.2
3004    0.3  1.0
```

```
df <- structure(list(Sample = c(3000, 3001, 3002, 3003, 3004), Au = c(0.2, 
0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3), Au_ppb = c("0.2", ">3", "0.2", "0.2", "1"
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

If Au and Au_ppb columns are the same, I want EQUAL and if they are not I want NOT EQUAL to appear in a new column. Example below.

```
Sample#  Au  Au_ppb newcol 
3000    0.2  0.2    EQUAL  
3001    0.2  >3     NOT EQUAL 
3002    0.2  0.2    EQUAL
3003    0.2  0.2    EQUAL
3004    0.3  1.0    NOT EQUAL
```

I think I need to use ifelse or case_when but I am not sure how. Any help is appreciated.
I have seen several posts that are similar, but the number of conditions are different in those, so I am not sure how to edit the code. I prefer using dplyr package. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What exactly did you try? Where did you get stuck? With `dplyr` this would be just `dd %>% mutate(newcol=if_else(Au==Au_ppb, "EQUAL", "NOT EQUAL"))` where `dd` is your data.frame.

Comment: I tried df %>% mutate(newcol = case_when(Au ==Au_ppb~ "EQUAL")) But it gave NA for all others.

Comment: You need to catch the other case in your `case_when`, its common to use `TRUE` to catch all other cases `df %>% mutate(newcol = case_when(Au ==Au_ppb~ "EQUAL", TRUE ~ "NOT EQUAL"))`

Answer (score 1):

I'd highly recommend using the actual logical values for true and false, rather than strings. It's faster, it takes up less space on your computer, it makes more elegant code, so it's better practice all-round.

```
df |> mutate(new_col = Au == Au_ppb)
```

Output:

```
  Sample  Au Au_ppb new_col
1   3000 0.2    0.2    TRUE
2   3001 0.2     >3   FALSE
3   3002 0.2    0.2    TRUE
4   3003 0.2    0.2    TRUE
5   3004 0.3      1   FALSE
```

If you *insist* on doing it with strings, you could use:

```
df |> mutate(new_col = if_else(Au == Au_ppb, "EQUAL", "NOT EQUAL"))
```

Or [`case_when()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html), as [discussed by Mr. Flick in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76972548/if-two-column-values-match-add-one-character-value-if-they-do-not-match-add-a#comment135691940_76972548).